Online Meeting sometimes fails to record automatically
I create calendar events at the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/calendar/events endpoint with "isOnlineMeeting": True. I then update this onlineMeeting to automatically record and other details, with an update request at https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/onlineMeetings/{meeting_id}.
So far so good, when a user joins the online meeting, it starts recording automatically. However, I have noticed that some of these events will not record automatically, even though they're all created with the exact same backend code.
Below are some screenshots showing the exact same meeting. The first screenshot shows the meeting starting and not being recorded.

The screenshot below is when we went to debug it. We inspected and saw no recording was done, so we joined the meeting again and it recorded automatically to our surprise.

Any idea what could be happening here? I can provide the meeting join link if necessary.
Note: the code that creates these meetings in our company has been live for years with no known issues like this. Could it have been a random one time bug within Microsoft?

I have received an answer from Microsoft. They said it was a service outage on that timeframe specifically.

1.Created a calendar event using Graph API having "isOnlineMeeting": true.

2.Then we tried to update the event to include property "recordAutomatically": true using below Graph API and encountered the error stating 'The property 'recordAutomatically' does not exist on type 'microsoft.graph.event'.

When we checked the official documentation, we observed that only these properties can be updated. (recordAutomatically property was nowhere to be found)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body
Update:
Tried with the suggested endpoint i.e. /onlineMeetings/{meeting_id}

and observed that after updating the meeting, when a user joins the online meeting, it starts recording automatically. I did check few times and observed same behaviour


You are using different endpoint to update meeting. The question mentions /users/{user_id}/onlineMeetings/{meeting_id}, you are using /users/{user_id}/calendars/event

Yes, as @user2250152 mentioned. You may wonder why I'm updating a meeting right after creating it, it's because the calendar event endpoint doesn't let me pick all the options I need, such as recording automatically or setting someone as coorganizer.

Tried with the suggested endpoint i.e. /onlineMeetings/{meeting_id} and observed that after updating the meeting, when a user joins the online meeting, it starts recording automatically. I did check few times and observed same behaviour.

@Prasad-MSFT Yes, it has worked for years in our company, but specifically on May 7th, 2024, we had about 20 of those meetings that simply were not recorded and their configuration was absolutely the same as every other meeting we have made.
My intent with this question is to find out why these meetings could have failed to record on that specific day, and how to avoid having it happen again. I have opened a ticket in Microsoft 365 to investigate further.
